# I am having troubles drawing a syntax tree for the sentence "networking helps you grow your business". Can anyone help me?

Tags: syntax-trees

I do not know if "helps" is a verb, an auxiliary verb, a tense, a complementizer phrase, or something else. Could someone attach a picture of the correct tree?

Comment: Help is not an auxiliary verb, but a verb that takes *object + bare infinitive (without "to")*, like *I made him cry, I saw him leave, I let him live,* and probably a few others.

Comment: @Cerberus what about "I helped to make him cry"?

Comment: @curiousdannii Good example. It looks like *help* is a control verb - specifically, this is an instance of partial subject control, where the PRO subject of the embedded infinitive has to at least contain the matrix subject as part of its reference. It seems like *help* can appear in a number of different frames.

Comment: @curiousdannii: The verb *help* can be used in/with different constructions: either with a bare infinitive or with a *to* infinitive. The rest is as usual.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about help with particular syntax trees.

Comment: If you want to post a "help me with my homework" question, you should post additional evidence of your efforts to find answers for it.

Answer (score 2):

I would analyse it like this:

[image: Syntax tree for "networking helps you grow your business"]

*helps* is definitely a verb - the /-s/ suffix is the third person present tense agreement marker.

I drew the tree with an internal sentence, but it might also be called an Inflection Phrase or a Tense Phrase. There's little consensus on the syntactic categories.

(You can make trees like this easily at http://ironcreek.net/phpsyntaxtree/)

Comment: I'd agree with that. The first word _networking_ may be a derived noun, as you have it, but it could also be the remains of a deceased gerund complement clause: i.e, [np [s [np `indef` np] [vp _networking_ vp] s] np]

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with @Cerberus that *help* in your sentence takes a direct object and a bare-infinitival clause as complements. *You* really feels like an argument of *help*, and therefore should be its direct object. There might also be some syntactic tests we can use to try to establish that. If *you* is a direct object, then it should be possible to move it up the sentence by using the cleft construction:

```
(1) It is you that networking helps grow your business (not me).
```

The problem with this test and others like it is that we can’t really find sentences where the main verb is followed by a noun phrase and a bare-infinitival clause and yet behaves differently with respect to the test. So we don’t have a contrast showing that in one such sentence the relevant noun phrase is a direct object and in another it is the subject of the embedded bare-infinitival.

In ch. 14 of *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (eds. Huddleston & Pullum), the same distinction is discussed regarding sentences where the main verb is followed by a noun phrase and a gerund-participial clause. It is established there that in (2), *Kim* is the direct object of the main verb, whereas in (3)  it is the subject of the embedded clause:

```
(2) He caught Kim drinking his beer.
(3) He resented Kim drinking his beer.
```

Does the clefting test distinguish between these two sentences? I’m not sure.

```
(4) It was Kim that he caught drinking his beer.
(5) It was Kim that he resented drinking his beer.
```

(4) is grammatical, as expected, but I’m not sure about (5) (I’m not a native speaker of English). If (5) is grammatical, this means that subjects of embedded non-finite clauses can be clefted.

The same holds for the relativization test (with an embedded bare-infinitival clause). Is (6) grammatical?

```
(6) You are the person whom networking helps make new connections.
```

To summarize, It would be nice to find syntactic tests clearly showing that *You* in *Networking helps you grow your business* is the direct object of the main verb.

In the meantime, here is a syntactic tree generated by [Contextors](http://contextors.com/) where *you* is the direct object (we follow the syntactic framework in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, where non-finite complements have the functional category *catenative complement*; also, we analyze *networking* as a gerund-participial clause).

[image]
[enlarge image](http://contextors.com/examples/networking_helps_you_grow_your_business.html)

Comment: Nice graph! What did you use to generate it?

Comment: Thanks, Otavio! The Contextors tree generator is not available for outside use at the present. We are working on making it public in the future.You are most welcome to subscribe to our mailing list to receive updates

Comment: Also, if you are wondering about specific sentences, you are most welcome to contact me through the [Contact section](http://contextors.com/#contact) on the Contextors website.